# Normality of conditional pdf(s) does not imply BVN

Tags: self-study, normality-assumption, distributions, bivariate, multivariate-normal-distribution

Show by means of example that the normality of conditional pdf(s) does not imply that the bivariate density is normal.

I know of the following example that if $\ U,V,W $ and $\ T$ are independently distributed with 
$U \sim N(0,1)$ 
$V \sim N(0,1)$ 
$W \sim N(0,1)$ and 
$T \sim U(0,1)$ , 
then $X = U\sqrt{T} + V\sqrt{1-T} \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = W\sqrt{T} + V\sqrt{1-T} \sim N(0,1)$ but $(X,Y)$ does not follow $BVN$ distribution.

Can this example be modified to answer the above question? If not, can someone please provide a suitable example.

Thanks!

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for pointing out. Just corrected my mistake.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer; it doesn't serve as an answer in its current state.

Comment: Something quite similar to your example does work (normal conditionals with non-normal joint) in the trivariate case; there's one in Stoyanov, *Counterexamples in Probability*, 3rd Ed, p97-98; immediately preceding that example is an example of a non-normal bivariate distribution with normal conditionals.

Comment: @Glen_b I had posted a comment but now it has vanished. I don't have access to the above mentioned book so I improvised my solution a bit to adhere to the requirements. $X| W \equiv X$ as $X$ and $W$ are independent of each other. Similarly, $Y| U \equiv Y$. Can you please suggest if my logic is correct or not?

Comment: I responded to it (to say "yes, X is independent of W and Y is independent of U"), but being a comment under my answer it was deleted when I later deleted my answer for not actually answering the question you asked.

Comment: So, does it mean that my reasoning is correct and that the above modification would make the counter-example a valid one?

Answer (score 4):

Let us define a bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ having pdf $f(x,y)$ as: 
$$f(x,y) = \lambda {e^{ - (1 + {x^2})(1 + {y^2})}}$$
where $- \infty  < x < \infty$ and $- \infty  < y < \infty$.
Clearly, $(X,Y) \nsim BVN$

Now the Marginal distribution of $X$ is obtained as follows:
$${f_X}(x) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f(x,y)dy}$$
$$= \lambda {e^{ - (1 + {x^2})}}\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{e^{ - (1 + {x^2}){y^2}}}dy} $$
Now using the fact that: $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{e^{ - a{x^2}}}dx = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{a}} } $, we have:
$${f_X}(x) = \lambda {e^{ - (1 + {x^2})}}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{1 + {x^2}}}} $$
Similarly, we can find the Marginal distribution of $Y$.
$${f_Y}(y) = \lambda {e^{ - (1 + {y^2})}}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{1 + {y^2}}}} $$
Now,
$$f(x|y) = \frac{{f(x,y)}}{{f(y)}}$$
$$= \frac{{\lambda {e^{ - (1 + {x^2})(1 + {y^2})}}}}{{\lambda {e^{ - (1 + {y^2})}}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{1 + {y^2}}}} }}$$
After simplifying a bit we will finally have,
$$= \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2(1 + {y^2})} }}} \right)}}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\left( {\frac{x}{{\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2(1 + {y^2})} }}}}} \right)}^2}}}$$
$$ \Rightarrow X|Y \sim N\left( {0,\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2(1 + {y^2})} }}} \right)$$
Similarly, we can show that $Y|X \sim N\left( {0,\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2(1 + {x^2})} }}} \right)$.

Hence, this example shows that the normality of the conditional pdf(s) *does not* imply that the bi-variate density is also normal.

Comment: +1 ... Is that the example from Stoyanov (it seems kind of similar to my recollection), or is that one of your own invention?

Comment: @Glen_b We had a discussion regarding this question in class, and our professor came up with the above density function as a hint. I thought that I would post the answer so that the question in complete.

Comment: Thanks - both for posting and answer and for the explanation of the source,